# how to count number of people who switch treatments over time SAS

Tags: sas, counting

I have a dataset with participants who are on either treatment A or treatment B and are followed up at different time intervals. For example, participant 1 might have visits at month 0 (baseline) and then at months 2, 6 and 12, but participant 2 might have visits just at baseline and at month 6 etc. I was wondering how I could count the number of people who switch from one treatment to another during any of their follow-up visits. I know it should be pretty straightforward to do but because the follow up visits are not the same for everybody, I cant seem to figure out how to deal with the missing data for some participants.

Here's an example of my data and what I've been trying to do. As you can see from the data, only participants 1 and 5 switched treatments during the duration of their follow-up but the variable "count" that I've created to take on the value 0 if participant doesnt switch and value 1 if they do switch, gets the value 1 everywhere...

```
DATA example;
 input PATID TRT$ VISNO WEIGHT;
 datalines;
1   A   0   95
1   A   2   96
1   B   6   96
1   B   12  99
2   A   0   80
2   A   6   81
3   A   0   98
3   A   4   120
4   B   0   100
5   A   0   102
5   B   6   95
5   A   12  98
run;
proc print data=example; run;

proc transpose data=example out=wide1 prefix=TRT;
    by patid;
    id visno;
    var trt;
run;

proc print data = wide1; title "Transposed data";
run;

data switchcount;
set wide1;
if TRT0=TRT2=TRT6=TRT12=TRT4 then count=0;
else count=1;
run;
proc print data=switchcount;
run;
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What does your desired result look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `PATID` that has every `VISNO`, thus every transposed row has at least one column with a missing value (corresponding to the non-present `VISNO`s within the `BY` group). The missing value not equal to any `VISNO` `TRT` present in the group, thus the TRT equality evaluation across the row will never assert to *true*, causing every row to contain `count=1`.

Presuming you want a count of `PATID` having more than one treatment, a SQL query can provide that.

Example:

```
proc sql;
  select 
    count(distinct patid) as result label="Number of patients with multiple treatments"
  from 
  ( select patid from example
    group by patid
    having count(distinct trt) > 1
  )
  ;
quit;
```

[image]

Similarly, for presorted data, a `DATA` step with DOW processing can compute the same count.

Example:

```
data want(keep=result);
  do until (last.patid);
    set example end=done;
    by patid;
    if trt ne lag(trt) then switch_count = sum(switch_count, 1-first.patid);
  end;

  result + switch_count>0;
  if done then output;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

we can use the lag function to find the treament from the previous visit and then check all rows if the treatment does not equal the previous treatment. To do, lets create the example dataset as follows:

```
 DATA example;
        input PATID TRT$ VISNO WEIGHT;
        datalines;
    1   A   0   95
    1   A   2   96
    1   B   6   96
    1   B   12  99
    2   A   0   80
    2   A   6   81
    3   A   0   98
    3   A   4   120
    4   B   0   100
    5   A   0   102
    5   B   6   95
    5   A   12  98
    run;
```

then we may want to make sure the example dataset is sorted by PATID and visno. This is to ensure that previous treatment is calclated for a same PATID from the prevous visit:

```
 proc sort data=example;
        by PATID visno;
    run;
```

now lets find the treatment for each PATID in the last visit. Here lag1 is used which finds the previous treatment and stores the value into a new field PREV_TRT. if statement is to ensure that the first row for each PATID has no PREV_TRT value.

```
data lagged_example;
    set example;
    by PATID;
    PREV_TRT=lag1(TRT);

    if first.PATID then
        PREV_TRT='';
run;
```

Finally we use proc sql to create a table followup_trt_change  that has all rows where the treatment is changed compared with the previous visit for each PATID. Note that this step is optional.

```
proc sql;
    create table followup_trt_change as select * from lagged_example where 
        TRT <> PREV_TRT and not missing(PREV_TRT);
quit;
```

The following finds all PATIDs that have at least once changed their treatment from their last visit.

```
 proc sql;
        select distinct PATID from lagged_example where TRT <> PREV_TRT and not 
            missing(PREV_TRT);
    quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just wanna find PATIDs that have changed their treatment any time in the course of visits (not from their last visit necessarily), meaning that PATIDs that have at least two treatments during their visits, you can simply use the following:

```
proc sql;
select PATID
from example
group by PATID
having count(distinct TRT) >=2
;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you, Esam, this is very neat and achieves exactly what I wanted!